# UUID less than 30 chars

Tags: php, uuid

I have a UUID in my system that is `105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34` long.
The problem is that when I sent this UUID to a web service they only accept UUID's 30 chars long.

Any idea how to convert this to 30 chars and then be able to somehow convert it to same length UUID ?

Basically:

1. My internal ID `105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34`
2. When I sent to the web service I want to convert to something 30
       chars.
3. When I get the response back I want that 30 char uuid to convert
       again as my internal ID `105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34`

Comment: If it's 30 chars, it's not an UUID, is it?

Comment: If each character in the UUID be truly random, then there is no way to convert from 30 up to your current length, because information will have been lost.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's random !

Comment: @MatteoTassinari apparently this web service they use 30 chars UUID's

Comment: Answer: You can only use a 30 character UUID.  Is this limit due to the API or is it a problem with a GET request becoming too long?

Comment: Please refer to the API documentation of the webservice.

Comment: @Gordon The web service response was that I need to sent a UUID 30 chars long.

Comment: Use internal map, generate something 30 chars long and map it to your GUID, so basically you will have GUID and "something30CharsLong" in one record. So you can look up by "something30CharsLong" and get original GUID

Answer (score 3):

UUID is represented in a hex string. You can convert it into a base 64 format removing the hyphens without losing any information. When converting it back remember to reintroduce the four hypens and lower case the string, details about the [format are here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format).

[Here one online converter from hex to base64 and from base64 to hex](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)

Comment: I didn't want to call the api in a base 64 way, I mean to convert the UUID hex string into a UUID base64 string. Is always a string so nothing must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution based on [@Phoenix idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765007/1548070):

```
<?php
$g = "105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34";

$e = encodeGUID($g);
var_dump($e);
$ge = decodeGUID($e);
var_dump($ge);

function encodeGUID($g)
{
    $t = str_replace("-", "", $g);
    return base64_encode(pack("h*", $t));
}

function decodeGUID($g)
{
    $g = implode('', unpack("h*", base64_decode($g)));
    return substr($g, 0, 8) . '-' . substr($g, 8, 4) . '-' . substr($g, 12, 4)
        . '-' . substr($g, 16);
}
```

result will be:

```
string(24) "AcVtCFpwEX555HvVchXfQw=="
string(35) "105cd680-a507-11e7-974eb75d2751fd34"
```

So encoded string has 24 characters, if you want exactly 30 symbols you can pad it by symbol which is not in use for base64 encoding, let's say `*`

so code will look like:

```
<?php
$g = "105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34";

$e = encodeGUID($g);
var_dump($e);
$ge = decodeGUID($e);
var_dump($ge);

function encodeGUID($g)
{
    $t = str_replace("-", "", $g);
    $e = base64_encode(pack("h*", $t));
    return str_pad(base64_encode(pack("h*", $t)), 30, "*");
}

function decodeGUID($g)
{
    $g = implode('', unpack("h*", base64_decode(trim($g, ' *'))));
    return substr($g, 0, 8) . '-' . substr($g, 8, 4) . '-' . substr($g, 12, 4)
        . '-' . substr($g, 16);
}
```

And it will return:

```
string(30) "AcVtCFpwEX555HvVchXfQw==******"
string(35) "105cd680-a507-11e7-974eb75d2751fd34"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not a PHP developer but I think to be a good thinker :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a anything wrong with just taking a substring of the UUID in your PHP code:

```
$uuid = "105cd680-a507-11e7-974e-b75d2751fd34";
$new_uid = substr($uuid, 0, 30);
```

Comment: then how do I map it back that substr to my UUID  ?

Comment: You don't, for the reasons already discussed.  If the API uses a 30 char UUID string, then you should use the same in your app code.

Comment: Before I comment further, check the other answer...is your API expecting base 64?

Comment: base 64 still doesn't meet the bank requirements, already tried that

Comment: Then you can pad the extra space with zeroes.

Comment: Taking a substring will increase the collision chances

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres True, but then again a random string of length 30 is still very unique.